# IdentityManager with VNext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, thinktecture

Has anyone tried using IdentityManager with vNext?

I'm having problems with the `app.UseIdentityManager(IdentityManagerOptions)` extension method.

It doesn't exist.

So I tried using the extension method made for `UseIdentityServer` (found [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/vNext/source/HostvNext/Config/IApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs)) by changing all the server related aspects to manager.
When I do that, I get the `System.NullReferenceException` in line 43.

Any kind of advice on how to go about with the extension method will be really appreciated

Comment: See this sample from IdentityServer3 where IdentityManager is implemented: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity/SelfHost

Sadly this sample is broken.

Comment: @CorstianBoerman. Thanks for the link. After playing around with IdentityManager and Server(for AspIdentoty) I figured the underlying problem is vNext works with Identity3 while identityserver and manager still use Identity 2.0. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Again, thanks for the sample link

Comment: That's true. I remided myself that I've read somewhere there were no plans to support asp.net 5 yet, whatsoever, it looks like they've changed their minds: https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/issues/144

Answer (score 0):

I am using ASPNET 5 beta6 and I got this to work.

Try using [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/dev/source/AspNet5Host/src/IdentityServerAspNet5/Configuration/IApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs) updated `IApplicationBuilder` extension found in the Samples repo on dev branch. Repurpose the method to accept IdentityManagerOptions rather than `IdentityServerOptions` and edit the builder to `UseIdentityManager`

In short here is what my extension method looks like

```
public static class IApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void UseIdentityManager(this IApplicationBuilder app, IdentityManagerOptions options)
    {
        app.UseOwin(addToPipeline =>
        {
            addToPipeline(next =>
            {
                var builder = new AppBuilder();

                var provider = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IDataProtectionProvider>();

                builder.Properties["security.DataProtectionProvider"] =
                    new DataProtectionProviderDelegate(purposes =>
                    {
                        var dataProtection = provider.CreateProtector(string.Join(",", purposes));
                        return new DataProtectionTuple(dataProtection.Protect, dataProtection.Unprotect);
                    });

                builder.UseIdentityManager(options);

                var appFunc =
                    builder.Build(typeof (Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>)) as
                        Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>;
                return appFunc;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm using vNext and I've noticed that many things have changed and will continue to change.

For my own needs I've been able to get identity up and running fairly easily and there are two steps that I've had to take to get it running properly. What I've done should work for you as well.

In your StartUp.cs  you will need to make sure you add the following to the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

In addition to that you will need to configure your app to use identity and to do this you need to do the following in your Configure() method:

```
app.UseIdentity();
```

Comment: You're talking about Identity. IdentityManager is some additional package which makes it easy to add users etc without writing some logic first. (See: https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager)